# How to use and access a template parameter pack of parameter packs

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

### Short Intro

I am trying to create a `AddComponents()` method that creates and adds multiple components to an entity at once. I have already written a working method to add one component at a time.

It has the following signature:

```cpp
template <class TComponent, typename... TArguments>
TComponent & AddComponent(TArguments&&... arguments);
```

and is used in the following way

```
entity.AddComponent<SomeComponent>(data1, data2, data3);
```

I would now like to make a function that adds multiple components at one i.e. takes a parameter pack of `TComponents`. Of course, the data must be passed as well and here is where things get ugly; I basically need a parameter pack of parameter packs. The function should then iterate over the `TComponents` (e.g. using `int i < sizeof...(Types)`) and call `AddComponent<T>(data...)` for each `TComponent`. I have worked with templates quite a bit but I struggle to get my head around this.

### What I want

Ideally, I want it to be used something like this:

```
entity.AddComponents<PositionComponent, SpriteComponent, TComponent>(
{ position },
{ texture, colour },
{ data1, data2 });
```

Internally I need a way to do something like

```
for each TComponent : TComponents
{
    this->AddComponent<TComponent>(forward...(data))
}
```

In theory, I might be able to get away without this but it seems like an interesting problem nevertheless.

### AddComponent Code

In case people might question what the function does here's the code.

```
template <class TComponent, typename... TArguments>
inline TComponent & Entity::AddComponent(TArguments&&... arguments)
{
    auto typeId = detail::GetComponentTypeID<TComponent>();

    auto component = std::make_shared<TComponent>(eventManager, *this, std::forward<TArguments>(arguments)...);

    componentList.push_back(component);
    componentDictionary.insert(std::make_pair(typeId, component));

    entityManager.AddEntityToGroup(*this, typeId);

    this->AddPolymorphism(typeId, component);
    eventManager.RaiseEvent(mbe::event::ComponentsChangedEvent(*this));

    return *component;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible exactly what do you ask. Maybe something as `entity.AddComponents<PositionComponent, SpriteComponent, TComponent>(
std::make_tuple(position),
std::make_tuple(texture, colour),
std::make_tuple(data1, data2));` coul'd be acceptable for you? Another question: you want a solution strictly C++11 or C++14 and C++17 are acceptable?

Comment: Whatever workes and gets closest :) Sure, make tuple isn't a deal breaker. I'm working with C++17 atm and I'll switch to C++20 when its released.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use something similar to what the STL ended up doing: Pass packs of packs as a pack of tuple.

Take emplace_back in a pair for example:

```
stuct Widget {
    int a;
    std::string name = {};
};

std::pair<Widget, Widget>{
    std::piecewise_construct,
    std::forward_as_tuple(12, "values"),
    std::forward_as_tuple(31)
};
```

Here the first parameter tell that you want piecewise construct, so each argument will act as a "pack" that will be expanded into the members of the pair. In this case, the elements of the pair was construct as if:

```
Widget first{12, "values"};
Widget second{31};
```

In your case, it seems you always want to construct `N` components. So the solution would be:

```
template<typename Component, typename Tuple>
void addComponentUnpack(Tuple&& tuple) {
    std::apply([](auto&&... args) {
        addComponent<Component>(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    }, std::forward<Tuple>(tuple));
}

template<typename... Components, typename... Tuples>
void addComponents(Tuples&&... tuples) {
    (addComponentUnpack<Components, Tuples>(std::forward<Tuples>(tuples)), ...);
}
```

So for each `Component`, you have a corresponding `Tuple` in the packs `Components` and `Tuples`. Then, each tuples are sent to a function that construct a single component of type `Component` using the tuple `Tuple`.

This example uses C++17 features such as *fold expressions* and `std::apply` but it can be implemented in C++14 with a bit more code.

---

If however you don't wish to use tuples as parameters, you could alway recieve instances of your types directly:

```
template<typename... Components>
void addComponents(Components&&... components) {
    // ...
}
```

It's usage would be like:

```
addComponents(
    PositionComponent{12, 43},
    CollisionComponent{},
    SpriteComponent{"texture name"}
);

// or

addComponents<PositionComponent, CollisionComponent, SpriteComponent>(
    {12, 42},
    {},
    {"texture name"}
);
```

Of course, that would require to move component from the parameters into the entity, which may not be entirely free, depending on the case.

Comment: C++17 is fine :)

Comment: Soooo neat! Wow! Just out of curiosity, is there any way to allow for using `addComponents<Comp1>({data1, data2, data3});` instead of `addComponents<Comp1>(std::forward_as_tuple(data1, data2, data3));` Perhaps using std::initialiser list or something

Comment: U kinda explain it in the beginning but I'm not sure how it translates to this case

Comment: @AdrianKoch initializer lists are not quite compatible with parameter packs. I'll add something to the answer

Comment: Would this be correct:
```template<typename ...TComponents>
  void Entity::AddComponents(TComponents && ...components)
 {
  (AddConstructedComponent<TComponents>(&components), ...);
 }```
and then the AddConstructedComponents' signature:
```template<class TComponent>
  void Entity::AddConstructedComponent(std::shared_ptr<TComponent> componentPtr)``` --> I'll admit I'm new to fold expressions

Comment: @AdrianKoch absolutely not. `...components` are most likely temporaries. Taking addess of them is not a good idea. You have to move them into a newly allocated shared pointer like so: `AddConstructedComponent(std::make_shared<TComponent>(std::forward<TComponent>(component)))`

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class...Ts>
struct types_t:
  std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Ts)>
{};
template<class T0, class...Ts>
struct types_t<T0, Ts...>:
  std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1+sizeof...(Ts)>
```

{
      using head=T0;
      using tail=types_t;
   };

```
template<class Componets>
auto ComponentWorker( Components ) {
  return [this](auto components, auto&&...args) {
    using TComp0 = typename decltype(components)::head;
    // add TComp0 using all of args...
    using TCompTail = typename decltype(components)::tail;
    if constexpr( TCompTail::value != 0 )
      return ComponentWorker( TCompTail{} );
    else
      return; // void
  }
}
template <class TC0, class... TCs, class... TArguments>
auto AddComponent(TArguments&&... arguments) {
  using components = types_t<TC0, TCs...>;
  return ComponentWorker( components )( std::forward<TArguments>(arguments)... );
}
```

the syntax here is:

```
AddComponent<A,B,C>( A_args... )( B_args... )( C_args... );
```

failing to pass arguments results in the component not being added.

Answer (score 2):

The best I can imagine is a recursive `addComponents()` that "consume" the first not deduced template type with the first deduced tuple list of argument and call itself with the remaining.

In C++17 you can also use `std::apply()`.

First of all, you need a ground case version of `addComponents()` (to interrupt recursion)

```
   template <int = 0>
   void addComponents ()
    { };
```

next the recursive version (EDIT: corrected from an error pointed by Guillaume Racicot; thanks!)

```
   template <typename T0, typename ... Ts, typename A0, typename ... As>
   void addComponents (A0 && tpl, As && ... as)
    {
      std::apply([](auto && ... args)
         { return addComponent<T0>(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); }, 
         std::forward<A0>(tpl));

      addComponents<Ts...>(std::forward<As>(as)...);
    }
```

Not sure about the correctness of perfect forwarding with tuples and `std::apply()` (sorry).

This, obviously, require that arguments for single component are packed in tuples.

So your call become

```
entity.AddComponents<PositionComponent, SpriteComponent, TComponent>(
   std::make_tuple(position),
   std::make_tuple(texture, colour),
   std::make_tuple(data1, data2));
```

**-- EDIT --** - I see now that Guillaume Racicot has substantially written the same solution but in a better C++17 style: using template folding and avoiding recursion. Very nice.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot - I know, but we have forwarding (if I'm not wrong) inside the lambda used by `std::apply()` that receive the values in the tuple. I'm not very good with forwarding but I see that you have written the same forward inside your lambda, so I'm more confident about correctness of my code.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot - I'm an idiot! I've initially used the `std::tuple<As...> &&` as first argument to deduce the types in the first tuple and use they to forward the `args...` in the lambda; next I have used `std::forward<decltype(args)>` instead of `std::forward<As>` and I've forgotten to simplify the first argument. Thanks for pointing it. Corrected (I hope).